# Global Property in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, global-variables

I have an enum defined in the Constants.h file this way:

```
typedef enum {
    CalendarTypeMonth = 0,
    CalendarTypeWeek
} CalendarType;
```

Then in my view controller I determine what the calendar type should be and store it in a property this way:

```
@property (nonatomic) CalendarType myCalendarType;
```

Now I want all the classes in my project have access to the calendar type. How can I set this property to be global/extern so that all classes can read this?

EDIT: I know the definition of the enum will be available across the project. But what I am interested in is the **value of `myCalendarType`**. How can I access the value of myCalendarType across all classes?

Comment: Either stash it in a singleton or stash it in your AppDelegate.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: Oh, there are so many possible reasons, I can't begin to guess what the downvoter had in mind: 1) Your question had virtually nothing to do with enums, 2) you don't understand that a property is already essentially `extern`, but there's no way to make it global without making the object containing it global, 3) you're apparently unfamiliar with both AppDelegate and singletons, even though you should have learned about AppDelegate at least while studying up on iOS before beginning coding.  And probably several others.

Comment: 3) AppDelegate is not meant for sharing data or for communicating between view controllers (Although you can use it for such things, its not what the AppDelegate is meant for). And creating a singleton  class for sharing a single variable is an overkill.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can declare class method to access static variable.

Add such code to your implementation file:

```
static MyStaticType staticVar = MyStaticTypeDefault;

+(BOOL)myStaticVar
{
    return staticVar;
}

+(void)setMyStaticVar:(MyStaticType)newValue
{
    staticVar = newValue;
}
```

And create declarations for this methods in interface file.
This is much better then moving all static values to AppDelegate.
Anyway, a lot of variants are possible - for example, you can create singletone to store some settings of application or use CoreData.

Comment: +1 Clear answer that works.  An alternative solution is to make a class that is a singleton.  You could then do something like `if ([MySingletonClass shared].myCalendarType == ...)`

Comment: How do static variables like this get retained/released etc.? Do they need to be explicitly set to nil?

Comment: If you don't specify the ownership qualifier it will default to `__strong` and be released when set to nil under ARC.

Comment: Yes, be aware of using this code with MRC - static variable won't be retained when set, will be deallocated at some point so you'd have a lot of fun searching for cause of unexpected crash

Answer (score -1):

In your [Project Name]_Prefix.pch file, you can add this statement:

```
#import "Constants.h"
```

In so doing, you'll make your enum available to every file in the project.

**EDIT:**
To access the value, I suggest making it a global property of your application delegate.  To take it a step further, you can make your application delegate a method of NSObject using a category so it might look something like:

```
CalendarType current = [self appDelegate].currentCalendarType
```

Observe that your property is now a globally gettable/settable property.

Comment: Thats a step better than my answer for making it global.