# Where to store the database path as a variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c

It's more a general question because I'm just starting iphone programming.

in all my views I have now multiple lines just for the path to the database that is stored in the document folder:

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
         NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
         NSString *path1 = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
         FMDatabase *db1 = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path1];
```

What is the used way of storing that path once as a 'global' variable, accessible in the whole project? Like the web.config in .net solutions.

Comment: The easiest way is the `NSUserDefaults` class, simple key-value storing, comparable with a ini-file in Windows.

Comment: you can always store it in your .pch file, so by default, it's accessible in whole project.

Comment: Why don't you create a manager object that encapsulates the access to the database with a number of methods? This class can be a singleton, which would provide a unique and centralised access across the entire application.

Comment: No need to create a manager object -- there already is one.  It's your subclass of "UIApplicationDelegate".

Comment: thanks ott, using the NSUserDefaults way !

Answer (score 0):

Create a static method in some class which returns the FMDataBase object defined above.

```
Class Aclass;

+(FMDataBase)database{
//do your stuff here, make sure to return the database object.
}
```

The database is now accessible via :

```
[Aclass database];
```

Don't forget to #import "Aclass.h"

You could also create a class variable in Aclass.m and initialise it first and the access it using a class method. Like this example:

[Global Property in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647331/global-property-in-objective-c)

Sorry for the formatting.

Comment: I would personally discourage this approach as it is a "global variable" type of mechanism. I would argue for using the singleton patterns instead.