# Global Property- objective c

Tags: objective-c, properties, global

I'm making an program, and it requires that properties in one View Controller be accessible by all classes. How would I make a global property?

Comment: Can't have a global property really unless you put it in the app delegate, which you shouldn't. Take look at this question the answer will show how to make a static helper. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647331/global-property-in-objective-c

Comment: Would someone tell me why that keep voting my posts down? It gets really annoying when I don't know what to change.

Comment: because you didn't search first, this question has been answered before.

Comment: I did do some searching, but as you said, not enough. I didn't see anything that had to do with properties though, just variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options:

1. Ideally, you should avoid making it a global, but rather pass the property from one view controller. See this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/1271826) for examples (such as setting it in `prepareForSegue`).
2. Alternatively, you can create a singleton, and make your property of that singleton. For example, `Model.h`:

   ```
   //  Model.h

   @import Foundation;

   NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

   @interface Model : NSObject

   @property (class, strong, readonly) Model *sharedModel;

   @property (nonatomic, copy, nullable) NSString *myString;

   - (id)init __attribute__((unavailable("Use +[Model sharedModel] instead")));
   + (id)new __attribute__((unavailable("Use +[Model sharedModel] instead")));

   @end

   NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
   ```

   and `Model.m`

   ```
   //  Model.m

   #import "Model.h"

   @implementation Model

   + (instancetype)sharedModel {
       static id sharedMyModel = nil;
       static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
       dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
           sharedMyModel = [[self alloc] init];
       });
       return sharedMyModel;
   }

   @end
   ```

   and then your various controllers can use this singleton class and reference that property you need accessible from other classes, such as:

   ```
   #import "SomeViewController.h"
   #import "Model.h"

   @implementation SomeViewController

   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       Model *model = [Model sharedModel];

       model.myString = @"abc";
   }

   @end
   ```

   and

   ```
   #import "AnotherViewController.h"
   #import "Model.h"

   @implementation AnotherViewController

   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       NSString *string = [[Model sharedModel] myString];

       // Do whatever you want with the string
   }

   @end
   ```
3. Your app actually already has a singleton, the app delegate, and you could add a property to that, and use that. For example, if you defined a property, `someOtherString` in the app delegate's .h, you could then reference it like so:

   ```
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   appDelegate.someOtherString = @"xyz";
   ```

   If I'm going to use a singleton for model data, I prefer to create my own, but this is another approach that some people use.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I see now that I may just use global variables, which are easier. Thanks anyway.